# MPI - HelloWorld Program in Python Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, mpi

I am trying to run a simple Hello World Program in mpi4py.

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import sys

size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()
rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
name = MPI.Get_processor_name()

sys.stdout.write(
    "Hello, World! I am process %d of %d on %s.\n"
% (rank, size, name))
```

I have saved this program on my desktop with name **h.py**

When i try to execute this program in **Anaconda Prompt** or **Command Prompt** using following command

```
mpiexec -n 4 python -m mpi4py h
```

It gives me error as can be seen in the image.

[image]

I am using windows 10.

EDIT:

@Gilles

[image: for]

**EDIT 2**

I have one more query which is I was trying the same thing yesterday and I installed MPI, Python 3.7 and Anaconda on my machine.

Then I created a similar program and saved it on my desktop with the name helloworld.py and also ran it on Jupyter Notebook.

Then i executed the program using this command.

```
mpiexec -n 4 python -m mpi4py helloworld
```

And it worked fine. But then i deleted the program. And wrote the program again this time with the name h.py and ran it again but it started giving me above error.

And one strange thing is even after deleting my **helloworld.py** program from everywhere in my local machine it still works when i execute it.

I am not sure how. Can you please help?

Comment: what if you `mpiexec -n 4 python -m mpi4py h.py` ?

Comment: It gives same error

Comment: it looks like `python` does not understand the `-m` flag. what if you `mpiexec -n 4 python h.py` ?

Comment: See my edited question

Comment: what if you `python --help` ? do you see a `-m` option ? you might also want to try `mpiexec -n 2 python h.py -m mpi4py`. if you plan to post something, please prefer plain text instead of screenshots.

Comment: Sorry about posting images.  I did python --help  and i see -m mod there. Also I did execute it using your second command and it worked. Can you please explain how? and what wrong I was doing.

Comment: Also, can you please see my edited question and answer that query aswell?